# Metro Bundler not starting in Docker with React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, docker, docker-compose, expo

I am trying to develop a Expo / React Native from a docker container;

So far i have the following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` in the root directory of my Expo app .. Whenever i run `docker-compose up -d`, it brings the container up but trying to hit the endpoint `localhost:9000` it just shows me json data about the expo project (which looks like a bigger version of the app.json) instead of the metro bundler webpage.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY app.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g expo-cli

EXPOSE 19000
EXPOSE 19001
EXPOSE 19002

CMD npm i -f && npm start
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   expo:
      container_name: expo-app
      build: ./
      ports:
        - 19000:19000
        - 19001:19001
        - 19002:19002
      volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/app
        - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      environment:
        - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
        - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=<<my_local_ip_address>>
```